# How do I make a SSRS 2008 R2 Ranged Bar Chart always show data labels?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a Range Bar Chart in SSRS 2008 R2 that is configured to look something like a Gantt Chart.  The Data set looks like:

Metric | Date-plot-1 | ... | Date-plot-n

My problem comes in with null values in Date-plot1.  If my report dataset returns a data value, I see the date labels on the bottom of the chart.  If that particular field is null, I either get no data labels, or "MM/dd/yyyy" (which is the formatting string I am applying to the dates).

Unfortunately, due to this being a data-quality report there can/will be NULL values in any/all of the columns.  How can I get the axis label to display even if the first date plot is null?

Comment: And before anyone asks, I tried to tag as "ssrs-2008-r2" but since I don't have the rep requirement, I couldn't.  Sorry if there is any r1/r2 confusion, but I am using R2, not "just" sql 2008

Answer (score 0):

what do you expect the values on the y axis to fall into if the X is null?

Nevertheless, I would deal with the null on the data source. Make it whatever value you answered my first question :)

If not possible, try to select the scale of the chart and see properties related with interval like intervalOffset.